pip installs package successfully but no executable present
I've installed great_expectations successfully using pip:
pip install great_expectations

after installation is complete I can see the package files under the site-packages folder. When I check the Scripts folder, there is no great_expectations.exe available.
Has anyone faced this issue and how did you resolve it?
I'm using python 3.12 and on Windows 10.

Why do you think an executable should be there?

setup.py on the project page doesn't show any exec wrappers nor does the readme mention anything about cli interface..

on the documentation post the install it says you should run great_expectations --version via the CLI, also, when i install it on another computer I do see an executable in the Scripts folder

I just ran pip install great_expectations with Python 3.9 on Linux and got no great_expectations script anywhere. I'm sure the post-install doc is wrong.

This I found at issues: "using a CLI command that is deprecated". Found at https://github.com/great-expectations/great_expectations/issues?q=is%3Aissue+script

Hmm, I think I found the issue, but let me confirm. It might have to do with version 0.18.21 vs 1.1.3. I will confirm between the setup.py files and post as an answer here.

Found the issue, so version 0.18.21 has a part for installing an executable in the setup.py file. I'm guessing this has been deprecated since GX Cloud is now the preferred method to use to interact or setup expectations.
Thanks all for pointing me in the right direction.
